# Why does nest() sometimes combine rows?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a tibble with 1755 rows.

The other question on my profile relates to setting this up.
The columns include a variable number of columns with name format "C1L", "C1H", "C2L" etc. always starting with c, no other columns start with c, and a column named "DI". I would like to nest these columns.

I run this code:

```
fullfile <- fullfile %>%
    nest(alleles = c(starts_with("C", ignore.case = FALSE), "DI"))
```

and get an output tibble with 1742 rows.

Looking in more detail, a subset of rows have two sets of data in the "alleles" column.
The affected rows are spread through the dataset, not clustered.

This is data from 16 groups, and each group has a probability related to each row.  This give me an easy measure - summing the probability column before the nest gives 16, afterwards gives 15.99826 so I'm definitely losing data, not just empty rows.

I'm looking for advice on what I can do to narrow down the cause of this issue.
I can't upload the example as I don't have permission to share the data I'm afraid.

Comment: That sounds normal. Nesting produces a tibble, in effect, with `df %>% group_by(unnested columns) %>% summarise(alleles = list of tibbles containing the nested columns)`.  So if you have several rows with identical values of the unnested variables, you will get nested tibbles with more than one row, and the corresponding unique values of the unnested variables (including your probability column) will only appear once.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. I hadn't realised it's got a grouping mechanism.  Is there any way to avoid that? If I was to temporarily add an indexing column maybe?

Comment: Yes, that would force it to single rows.  It depends on why you want to do the nesting. If you only have a list of single-row tibbles in the nested column, then for most purposes I'd have thought it would be easier to just work with the unnested tibble.

Comment: I want to pass the tibble to an existing function as an argument, but there may be better times to do that.